# In theory, does the form of the latent dynamics matter?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, latent-variable

I am experimenting with latent variable models of the form

$\mathbf{x}_t = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{z}_t + \mathcal{E}_t$ where $\mathcal{E}_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2\mathbf{I})$ and $\mathbf{z}_t \sim \mathcal{D}$ follows some $\textbf{latent}$ dynamics $\mathcal{D}$, that is $\mathbf{z}$ is unobserved (but $\mathbf{x}$ is, and it is my data). For example if $\mathbf{z}_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I})$ then we have the PPCA model (Bishop and Tipping 99).

Because of the latent variable, my likelihood is then $\sum_t\log p(\mathbf{x}_t) = \sum_t\log \sum_{\mathbf{z}_t}p(\mathbf{x}_t,\mathbf{z}_t)$ which is typically not tractable and hence must be maximised using the EM algorithm.

Now, and this is where I'm intrigued, I run EM and end up with the same estimates of $\mathbf{W}$ if I vary $\mathcal{D}$ i.e. regardless of the chosen form of the dynamics of $\mathbf{z}$. I can't quite fathom what is going on.

On one hand, it is clear that in the equivalent $\textbf{complete}$ (observed $\mathbf{z}$) case,  the problem boils down to regressing $\mathbf{x}$ on $\mathbf{z}$ and the dynamics of the latter is irrelevant. In that case we find the true $\mathbf{W}^*$ and we're done. Going one step further, I suppose that if we assume EM can possibly arrive (despite the well-known local minima problems) at the correct ML estimates of the model, then it must be at best $\mathbf{W}^*$. Then you would conclude that all different models fitted with EM could converge to that same $\mathbf{W}^*$ and indeed you would see what I see.

On the other hand, it just totally baffles me that my underlying latent dynamics doesn't actually seem to matter w.r.t. estimating $\mathbf{W}$. After all, we need $p(\mathbf{z}|\mathbf{x})$ to run EM, and this most obviously depends on $\mathcal{D}$.

Any theoretical insights?

Comment: Two questions. Are you suggesting that if $x_t$ is given, but you change $p(x_t, z_t)$, you still get the same estimate of $W$. Also $W$ is a linear transform, right?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{W}\mathbf{z}$ is just a matrix-vector product ie linear transformation. That's right, if I change the form of the dynamics of $\mathbf{z}$, then I must be changing $p(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$ too, and yet, I get the same result. More precisely actually if I run EM with many starts to try and find $\mathbf{W}_{\mathcal{D}_2}$ I cannot exceed the likelihood I get by initialising EM at $\mathbf{W}_{\mathcal{D}_1}$. That's not exactly what I was saying actually, but it's still pretty strange.

Comment: I was thinking the univariate case might be the place to start. For a given $x_t$, exchanging $z_t \sim \mathcal N (0, 1)$ with $\mathcal N (\mu , 1)$, for $\mu \neq 0$, would tend to move the MLE of $w$ towards zero. But I'm not sure.